# Initialize a Struct containing a const array with initializer list

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization

I working with C++11 and have a Class containing the following Struct:

```
struct Settings{
    const std::string name;

    const std::string* A;
    const size_t a;
};

class X {
    static const Settings s;
    //More stuff
};
```

In the `.cpp` file I want to define it like this

```
X::s = {"MyName", {"one","two","three"}, 3};
```

But this does not work. However it does work using an intermediate variable

```
const std::string inter[] = {"one","two","three"};
X::s = {"MyName", inter, 3};
```

Is there a way to do it without the intermediate variable?

Comment: Your struct *does not* contain a const array. It contains a pointer to a const string. With that in mind, it should be easy to see why you need the "intermediate variable".

Comment: @juanchopanza: Well, I want `A` to point to (the beginning of) a const Array. It could also be a pointer to a `const std::string`, but thats not what I want. But maybe I don't quite get what you are pointing at...

Comment: @Haatschii: you're confusing the fact that an array decays into a pointer with the idea that an array and a pointer are identical.  In terms of the language semantics, an array is not a pointer.  Likewise, an initializer list is not an array.  The compiler can initialize an array with such a list, and it can decay an array into a pointer, but it doesn't know in your example to convert the list into an array and then decay that to a pointer.  Hence the need for the intermediary, to get the initializer list converted to a contiguous array before assigning to the pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A pointer cannot be initialized from a list of values. You could use `std::vector` instead:

```
#include <vector>

struct Settings{
    const std::string name;
    const std::vector<std::string> A;
//        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    const size_t a;
};
```

You can then write:

```
class X {
    static const Settings s;
    //More stuff
};

const Settings X::s = {"MyName", {"one","two","three"}, 3};
```

Here is a [*live example*](http://ideone.com/o1wyTK).

[As suggested by Praetorian in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16676973/initialize-a-struct-containing-a-const-array-with-initializer-list/16677023#comment23997230_16677023), you may want to replace `std::vector` with `std::array`, if it is acceptable for you to specify the size of the container explicitly, and if the size does not need to change at run-time:

```
#include <array>

struct Settings{
    const std::string name;
    const std::array<std::string, 3> A;
//        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    const size_t a;
};
```

And here is the [*live example*](http://ideone.com/q9TUMu).

Comment: Could you explain why using vector makes the difference?

Comment: @taocp: Because a pointer cannot be initialized with a list of values. What you want is something that can be initialized from an initializer list

Comment: Or `std::array<std::string, 3>` if you don't need for it to be resizable.

Comment: @Praetorian: Indeed, if the user accepts to write the size explicitly

Comment: Thanks! I, hoped to get around using a vector but from your explanation I guess there is no way. `std::array` is no alternative since I can't specify the array size in the definition of the struct. By the way, is there any difference between a `const std::vector` and a `const std::array`, except that the size of the array must be given at the definition? (More a new question, but it just came to my mind)

Comment: @Haatschii: You cannot alter the content of a `const` array (e.g. `arr[0] = "Hello"`) ;)

Comment: @AndyProwl: Uh? But I could with a `const std::vector`?

Comment: @Haatschii: Woops, sorry, I misread your question. No, of course you can't modify a `const` vector, please disregard what I wrote. The difference is that `std::vector` will perform a run-time allocation that will get memory from the heap, while `std::array` is a thin, zero-overhead wrapper over a C-style array.

Answer (score 5):

That's because you're storing a pointer to an array of strings, not the strings themselves; so you need an array of strings somewhere to point to. All you have is a brace-initialiser containing pointers to character arrays.

If you were to store the strings themselves (in a `vector<string>`, for example), then the first version would work.